# Как вызвать методы модуля livedb-mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb

В скаченном модуле livedb-mongo есть файл mongo.js. Так вот в прототип функции LiveDbMongo записаны методы, которые я вызываю так:

```
var livedb = require('livedb-mongo');

livedb.LiveDbMongo('localhost:27017/test?auto_reconnect', {
 safe: true
}).getSnapshot('userchat', {
 name: 'John Savage'
}, function (err, doc) {
// body...
    if (!err) {
     console.log(doc);
    } else {
     console.log(err);
    }
});
```

но почему то он мне выдает ошибку.

Cannot call method 'getSnapshot' of undefined

Правильно ли я все делаю?

Comment: Попробуйте так

   livedb('localhost:27017/test?auto_reconnect', {safe: true})
      .getSnapshot('userchat', {name: 'John Savage'}, function (err, doc) {
          // some code
      });

Comment: спасибо работает можно и так 

var mongoskin = require('mongoskin');
var skin = mongoskin.db('localhost:27017/test?auto_reconnect', {safe:true});

var livedbmongo = require('livedb-mongo');
var mongo = livedbmongo(skin);

mongo.writeSnapshot('userchattuts',{name:'John Savage'},{age:28},function (err,rezult){
 if (!err) {
  console.log(rezult);
 }else {
  console.log(err);
 }
});